# Использование одной функции click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста можно ли использовать одну функцию для нескольких задач.

Пример №1:

1) Есть поля с id — #p1, #p2, #p3

2) Есть кнопки с id — #b1, #b2, #b3

при клике на поле (например с id - p1), должна вызываться функция и происходить действие с кнопкой у которой id - b1

```
$('#p1').click(function () {
    $('#b1').iCheck('uncheck');;
});

$('#p2').click(function () {
    $('#b2').iCheck('uncheck');;
});

$('#p3').click(function () {
    $('#b3').iCheck('uncheck');;
});
```

Можно ли как-то объединить (сократить) код? 
Сейчас все работает хорошо, но смущает тот факт что если много полей и кнопок, соответственно и много кода.

Если просто ID прописать списком, то при клике на какое либо одно поле естественно происходит действие со всеми кнопками (чего не нужно в итоге).

```
$('#p1, #p2, #p3 ').click(function () {
    $('#b1, #b2, #b3').iCheck('uncheck');;
});
```

Спасибо.

Comment: Да, можно. Задача в том, как понять какая кнопка связана с полем? Это можно сделать двумя способами, исходя из имен айдишников (поле с кнопкой связано именем айдишника) и исходя из разметки (поле и кнопка связаны html структурой). В первую очередь надо понять какой нужен по смыслу)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Первый вариант обойтись циклом, например:

```js
var COUNT_OF_FIELDS = 3;
for (var i = 1; i <= COUNT_OF_FIELDS; i++) {
  (function (i) { 
    $('#p' + i).click(function () {
        //$('#b'+i).iCheck('uncheck');
        console.log($('#b'+i).text());
    });
   }(i));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="p1">p1</p>
<b id="b1">b1</b>
<p id="p2">p2</p>
<b id="b2">b2</b>
<p id="p3">p3</p>
<b id="b3">b3</b>
```

Но это несколько избыточно.

Поэтому лучше на основе html разметки просто плясать от тега `p` (или что там под айдишниками скрывается), на который нажали и искать соответствующий ему `b`

пример

```js
$('p').on('click', function(){
 var bTag = $(this).next('b');
 console.log(bTag.text());
  //bTag.iCheck('uncheck');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p>p1</p>
  <b>b1</b>
</div>
<div>
  <p>p2</p>
  <b>b2</b>
</div>
<div>
  <p>p3</p>
  <b>b3</b>
</div>
```

Не знаю какая у вас html разметка, но наверняка также можно выделить что-то общее и сделать клик именно по нему и найти соответствующий ему `b`.

Comment: "это несколько избыточно" - это просто неправильно

Comment: @Igor ну отчего же. есть случаи когда приходится слушателей добавлять в цикле и это неизбежно...Тем не менее, как я и описал ниже, скорее правильней сделать не циклом а на основе общности данных, например зная, что один элемент находится под другим и т.д. А вы считаете ваш ответ верным и не рекомендуете ТС избавиться от избыточного количества id, а просто даете подходящий костыль?) Ну хорошо)

Comment: @Igor, если это выполняет поставленную, то это уже не неправильно

Comment: @ИгорьПоляков -  чему будет равно `i` в момент выполнения строки кода `$('#b'+i).iCheck('uncheck');;`?

Comment: Хотя все-таки соглашусь, приведенная реализация с циклом неверна. внутри click у переменной `i` всегда будет значение `COUNT_OF_FIELDS`

Comment: @Grundy точно. Так лучше? или наоборот?)

Comment: @Igor хорошо, поспешил. Поправил.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутые решения. Оба варианта работают отлично.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("[id^='p']").click(function () {
  var bId = this.id.replace("p", "b")
  $("# + bIdi).iCheck('uncheck');
});
```

Comment: Спасибо. Все работает. Скажите пожалуйста, а можно ли такой вариант использовать не с ID, а с классом? (class="pole pole1"; class="knopka knopka1") и и.д?

Answer (score 0):

Привязать селекторы целей к кликабельным элементам:

```js
$("#p1, #p2, #p3").click(function() {
  var targetSelector = $(this).attr("data-target");
  $(targetSelector).iCheck("uncheck");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="p1" data-target="#b1">p1</p>
<b id="b1">b1</b>
<p id="p2" data-target="#b2">p2</p>
<b id="b2">b2</b>
<p id="p3" data-target="#b3">p3</p>
<b id="b3">b3</b>
```